# SQL return multiple count statements

Tags: sql, count

I have a table which contains ski resorts around the world.  The table also identifies which country and "sector" (USA/Europe/Asia etc.) they are located in.  I'm trying to determine the number of resorts in each sector.

Sample Data :

```
resort_id, resort_name, country_id, sector_id
3376    Chréa           204  204
3377    Tikjda          204  204
3384    Beidahu         208  205
3481    Canyon Ski Area 225  206
3482    Castle Mountain 225  206
3483    Drumheller      225  206
```

I need to be able to determine the number of resorts in each sector i.e. :

```
Sector       Resorts
--------------------
204          2
205          1
206          3
```

Any help would be much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select sector_id,
       count(*)
from   resortTableName
group by sector_id
```

and to address your edited question:

```
select sector_id,
       count(distinct resort_name) as resortCount,
       count(distinct country_id) as countryCount
from   resortTableName
group by sector_id
```

Comment: However, in my haste, I've oversimplified my question.  I also need to determine the number of countries in each sector in the same query, thus the "multiple" of the title.  Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to `count` and group the results by the sector:

```
SELECT   sector_id, COUNT(*)
FROM     resorts
GROUP BY sector_id
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple `group By`

```
Select count(*) As Resorts, sector_id as Sector 
from yourtablename 
group by sector_id
```